# Excel: Count If (Comparing column1 > column2)

Tags: excel-formula

I need to compare two columns and find the count of number of IDs that match a certain criteria.

```
A            B                C
ID:       ListNum:         RefNum:
1           10                5
2            3                7
3           12                8  
4            2               15
5            4               11  
6            6                9
```

Let's say that the cell containing ID = "1" is A2 and it goes down to A7

I have to count the number of IDs that have a ListNum that is higher than the RefNum.

I used the following formula:
    =COUNT(IF(B2:B7 > C2:C7))

Is this the right way to calculate this or am I wrong?
(The final answer should be 2)
Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B7>C2:C7))
```

It returns `2`

Let me know if this helps.